# Smoothing values across an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, web-audio-api

I'm using the WebAudio API and the Analyzer node to visualize FFT data from an audio file.

You can see a demo of it here: 
http://vagrantsophist.com/effects/audio.html
(NOTE: Only works with Chrome for the moment and it takes a few seconds for the audio file to spool up depending on your internet connection.)

**My issue:**

The slider on the right is supposed to determine the smoothing value for the visualization. 
Here's the javascript code I'm using for it:

```
 function smoothArray(array, smoothing) {
    var newArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0;

        for (index = 0; index < (smoothing*2)+1; index++) {
            var thisVal = i - smoothing;
            if (thisVal < 0) {
                thisVal += array.length;
            };
            if (thisVal > array.length) {
                thisVal -= array.length;
            }
            sum += array[thisVal];
        }
        newArray[i] = sum/((smoothing*2)+1);
        index = 0;
    }

    return newArray;
}

var clippedArray = dataArray.subarray(0, 180);

var smoothedArray = smoothArray(clippedArray, document.getElementById("smoothing").value);
```

In theory, this should be adding the preceding values, the current values, and the following values and pulling an average of the sum.

For some reason though, it's offsetting the array by `smoothing` instead.

I've been playing with it for an hour and I can't see what's going on here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you calculate the average, you're dividing by `smoothing*2+1` even if some of those elements were skipped because they're outside the array.

Comment: Never mind -- you're not skipping them, you're wrapping around. You could just use `sum += array[thisVal % array.length]`

Comment: Huh, I'm not familiar with that. What's the called so I know how and when to use that shortcut in the future?

Comment: It's called _modulus_.

Comment: Why aren't you using `index` anywhere in the inner loop?

Comment: Thanks. Looking into modulus operators now.

Also, I'm not using `index` anywhere because I'm only using it to iterate accros the total number of smoothed values. It's not actually an index of any array. `i` is getting used for that on the previous loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just subtracting the same `smoothing` offset each time through the inner loop, you're not accessing all the surrounding elements of the array. You need to iterate `index` from `i - smoothing` to `i + smoothing`, and then average those elements of the array.

```js
function smoothArray(array, smoothing) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0;

        for (index = i - smoothing; index <= i + smoothing; index++) {
            var thisIndex = index < 0 ? index + array.length : index % array.length;
            sum += array[thisIndex];
        }
        newArray[i] = sum/((smoothing*2)+1);
    }

    return newArray;
}

var clippedArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
var smoothedArray = smoothArray(clippedArray, 2);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(smoothedArray);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This still isn't working.

I just updated the javascript to reflect your suggested change but debugging shows that `sum` inflates off into infinity.

Comment: I had an error in my use of modulus, because I forgot that it doesn't work properly for negative numbers; that was causing some null values at the beginning, but otherwise the code was right. I fixed that, see the demo.

Comment: Hm... Something still seems wrong.
1. The values output by your demo can't be right. (1+2+3+16+15)/5 = 7.4 (not 6.8). Also, at any point on the array past 2 and before 14 in your example, the value should be equal to the index - 1. (Example, smoothedArray[2] in your example should equal 3.)
2. `sum` is reaching values of 200k. (Which can't happen since the max value for any index of the array doesn't exceed 255.
I'm sure you see something I don't, but this still isn't working.

Comment: When did you try it? I had a bug earlier, I fixed it in my last edit. The inner loop was using `index < i + smoothing` when it should have been `index <= i + smoothing`.

Comment: I just tried it and have been playing with your demo just now too.

Your example i only pulling one value above the index and is pulling two from below, so the code snippet example here returns false numbers since it divides by 5 after that.

The number of iterations isn't the issue here. It's impossible for `sum` to reach 200k+ with a proper algorithm since 255*7 = 1785 at its max value.

Still testing though.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I just tried my example, and the first value is 7.4, just like you say it should be.

Comment: I just figured it out.

It was iterating through waaaay too many times because it was treating `smoothing` as a `String` and not an `Int`. I used `parseInt` and that cleaned up the issue.

It shows up as 7.4 now... I just ran the test a minute ago and it was 6.8 for some reason. Looks good now.

Thanks for you help!